# Посылка ajax запроса при нажатии enter из input text

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Доброго.

```
//ajax.php
<?
print_r($_POST);
echo '
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    function update(){
                        $(".buttonUpload").submit(function(){
                            $.ajax({
                                url:"ajax.php",
                                type:"POST",
                                cache:true,
                                data: "id="+$(this).attr("value"),
                                success: function(html){
                                    $(".ajaxid").html(html);
                                    update();
                                }
                            })
                        });
                    }
                    update();
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <input id="15" class="buttonUpload" value="101">
                <input id="16" class="buttonUpload" value="115">
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
            <div class="ajaxid"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
';
?>
```

Собственно, набираем в формочке что-либо, нажимаем 'enter' - посылается POST запрос, в случае если у полей есть 'name'. В текущей формочке 'name' нету, т.к. хочу реализовать отправку через ajax, но до меня не дошло как.

Вот, допустим, в форме несколько полей, name отсутствуют, да и не нужны, по сути. Забиваем в каком-либо поле значение, нажимаем enter. Как это превратить в POST запрос для AJAX? Код, который указал выше, - все, до чего догадался. Может кто подсказать, как довести до рабочего вида код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То есть вам нужно отследить нажатие на Enter и по этому событию отправить запрос? Думаю, это вам поможет http://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events

Answer (score 0):

```
//ajax.php
<?
if(!empty($_POST)){
print_r($_POST);
} else {
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".buttonUpload").click(function(){
          $.ajax({
            url:"ajax.php",
            method:"POST",
            data: {
              id: $(this).attr("value"),
              input_15: $('#input_15').val(),
              input_16: $('#input_16').val()
            },
            success: function(html){
              $(".ajaxid").html(html);
            }
          });
        return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="input_15" value="101">
    <input id="input_16" value="115">
    <input type="submit" class="buttonUpload" value="click me">
    <div class="ajaxid"></div>
  </body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Только не понял, что Вы подразумеваете под "enter". Судя по коду - кнопку на странице. Тогда это должно работать.

про Enter:
    http://poleshuk.ru/lovim-nazhatie-enter-v-nuzhnom-tekstovom-pole/

Comment: не, не кнопку. ввели что то в поле и нажали на клавиатуре. собственно, что то стандартное я бы и сам написал. как написать гомосятину - не знаю

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Я использую такой вариант. Пример:

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="form_who_should_be_checked">
    <input name="anything" value="">
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById("form_who_should_be_checked").onsubmit=
function() {
    alert(this.anything.value);
    return false;
}
</script>
```